# Is it possible to decode EventValidation and ViewState in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, decode

How to decode the ASP.NET EventValidation and ViewState?

Comment: For ViewState, see "How to decode viewstate": [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814/how-to-decode-viewstate/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814/how-to-decode-viewstate/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered a similar question recently, [Getting values from viewstate using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050902/getting-values-from-viewstate-using-jquery/1051069#1051069).

Basically, by default `ViewState` is just Base64-encoded, so you can decode it as long as the administrator hasn't configured the site to encrypt it. Quoting from my previous answer:

> If you are writing the control for
>   your own consumption and you only need
>   to read from `ViewState`, you could do
>   so, but I wouldn't recommend it unless
>   you find a well-debugged library to
>   parse it for you. The format is a bit
>   hairy (see [ViewState: All You Wanted
>   to Know for more details](http://aspalliance.com/135)).

That link provides an extremely thorough and clear introduction to `ViewState`.

As for Event Validation, I'm unsure whether it's Base64-encoded or if it just looks like Base64 (I can't find a conclusive, authoritative reference). [This Rexiology article](http://blogs.msdn.com/rextang/archive/2007/12/26/6868950.aspx) might help though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about EventValidation, but you can decode ViewState by using Fritz Onion's [ViewState Decoder](http://alt.pluralsight.com/tools.aspx).

Comment: Looks like Fritz pulled down the utility. A Google search pulls up this one first (http://ignatu.co.uk/ViewStateDecoder.aspx) but I cannot vouch for it. A shame really, Fritz' contribution was quite good.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to decode ViewStates recently and found this tool useful: [View State decoder](http://viewstatedecoder.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: @mrGreenBrown Just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple windows app and use `Convert.FromBase64(str)` to decode `ViewState` data if it is not encrypted.

Note: GridView causes encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285126/decoding-a-viewstate-string-with-utf-8-in-python-3/63394132#63394132)  if use python.

Best way is use this [link](https://pypi.org/project/viewstate/).

A small Python 3.5+ library for decoding ASP.NET viewstate.

First install that:   `pip install viewstate`

```
>>> from viewstate import ViewState
>>> base64_encoded_viewstate = '/wEPBQVhYmNkZQ9nAgE='
>>> vs = ViewState(base64_encoded_viewstate)
>>> vs.decode()
('abcde', (True, 1))
```