# Decoding a VIEWSTATE string with UTF-8 in Python 3

Tags: python, utf-8, base64, viewstate

I'm having trouble decoding a ASP.NET view state string in Python 3.
When I try decoding the string using bash's `base64` command, it decodes the string successfully and I'm able to see all the information I need (most of it is in Hebrew, meaning UTF-8). The view state is of course base64-encoded only and not encrypted.

However, when I try do decode the string using Python's `base64` library and then decoding the byte array to a UTF-8 string, I get an error message:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
>   0: invalid start byte

I should mention that since the string is a view state, the first few bytes are binary data and "0xff" makes sense, however after these bytes the data is readable.

Python 3 code segment:

```
b = "The_ViewState"
print(base64.b64decode(b).decode("utf-8"))
```

Why does decoding work in bash and not in Python? How can this be resolved?

Comment: Presumably Bash is ignoring bytes it cannot decode, not a good option in a programming environment where invalid input may be an error. Why not just skip those first few bytes?

Comment: You did not share your Bash code, however, nor any sample viewstate string.

Comment: Besides, the viewstate contains a whole *object graph*, you need to actually parse those binary bits to get to the interesting data.

Comment: In short, you'd need to write a parser for the Microsoft LOS format; this is not necessarily trivial! See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic11 for a starting point; the binary values are probably [object type identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.objectstateformatter(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little bit of research I found the answer:

```
b = "The_ViewState"
print(base64.b64decode(b).decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
```

Adding the "ignore" flag causes `decode()` to discard any invalid byte sequences, thus leaving the irrelevant bytes out of the decoded string.

Answer (score -1):

Best way is use this [link](https://pypi.org/project/viewstate/).

A small Python 3.5+ library for decoding ASP.NET viewstate.

First install that:   `pip install viewstate`

```
>>> from viewstate import ViewState
>>> base64_encoded_viewstate = '/wEPBQVhYmNkZQ9nAgE='
>>> vs = ViewState(base64_encoded_viewstate)
>>> vs.decode()
('abcde', (True, 1))
```